# PHP product price and quantity does not multiply

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build an ecommerce site and in my cart page the quantity and product price does not multiply. It returns 0. If the user adds a product in the cart it returns the quantity 1 and the price 0, it he adds another one the quantity is updated and the price is 0. The $price= $price * $each_item['quantity']; doesn't work properly. Here is the code. Thank you so much for your answers!

```
$i=0;
foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $each_item){
    $i++;
    $item_id=$each_item['item_id'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $product_name= $row["product_name"];
        $price=$row["price"];
    }
    $price= $price * $each_item['quantity'];
    $cartOutput.= "<h2>Product number: $i</h2>";
    $cartOutput.= "<p>Product ID:".$each_item['item_id']."</p>"."<br/>";
    $cartOutput.= "<p>Quantity:".$each_item['quantity']."</p>"."<br/>";
    $cartOutput.= "<p>Product name:".$product_name."</p>" ."<br/>";
    $cartOutput.= "<p>Price:".$price ."</p>"."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your database contains non-zero values in the price column?

Comment: What's the content of $row["price"]?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! It was just a stupid mistake that I've made. In the database in the price column all the prices were in html paragraph tags. It was so obvious the quantity couldn't be multiplied with this. But I forgot I wrote them this way. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. `mysql` is deprecated and can lead you to a whole lot of trouble. Think about SQL Inyection.

Here is more info about PDO
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Here is info about mysqli 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

1. Make sure data is added to the session array when an item is added to the "cart".. A good practice could be to set quantity as 1 by default.

Comment: All of this "answer" would be better off in the comment box

Comment: Thank you for your answer and links! It was just my mistake. In the database in the price column all the prices were in html paragraph tags.